# How to get message of rewrapped exception?

Tags: java, exception

I develop a EJB service and I my service can throw only one type of exception - `MyServiceException`. I.e. all occurred exceptions are wrapped into `MyServiceException` and rethrowed to client. But I don't want to show stack-trace  to client (for security reasons), and I want only log this stack-trace and show to client only error message. So simply writing following code will be enough:

```
catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("Error when creating account", e);
  throw new MyServiceException("Error when creating account" + e.getMessage());
}
```

But what if I have stack of methods: 1 -2 -3. And method 3 throws meaningful exception with message `"Not enough money"`, so *I want to show this message to client*. But method 2 rewrap this exception with new message `"Some problem with your credit card"`, so calling `e.getMessage()` in method 1
 will return only `"Some problem with your credit card"`, not `"Not enough money"`.. How to work with exceptions in this case? How to get all messages threw by me?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your code I would suggest you wrap exceptions in a different way:

```
catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("Error when creating account", e);
  throw new MyServiceException("Error when creating account" + e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Note the second parameter in MyServiceException constructor. This constructor should call super(message, throwable) constructor of its superclass.

If it's done this way, then you can get original exception by calling exception.getCause() method. And consequently exception.getCause().getMessage() to obtain its original message.

Usually, all third party APIs do exception wrapping like described above, so you should have no problem referring to the cause in exceptions from well designed libraries.

UPDATE: Sample of code that combines exception messages and separates them with new line character. I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure it's working and what's more important illustrates how to do what you were trying to do:

```
private static String printExceptionMessages(Throwable throwable) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    Throwable t = throwable;
    while (t != null) {
        result.append(t.getMessage());
        result.append('\n');
        t = t.getCause();
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Ok. But how I know how many times I need to call `exception.getCause()`. What if exception was wrapped many times? In other words I want to have ALL error messages threw by me, but not provide stack-trace to client.

Comment: You can call getCause() recursively until it returns null. The contract is that null cause indicates the very first original exception thrown.

Comment: Please see the code for Throwable.printStackTrace(PrintStream s) method.